# I don't understand why this function's output is one

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, matrix

This a code a made to move rows in a (3*3) matrix.

```
const transY =(arr)=> {
    const arrtY = []; 
    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (i==3) {
                return arrtY.unshift(arr[3*0+j]);
            }
            return arrtY.push(arr[3*i+j]);
        }
    }
    return arrtY;
}
```

Expected output (in an array) :

```
1  2  3       7  8  9       4  5  6
4  5  6  ==>  1  2  3  ==>  7  8  9 ==>  [...]
7  8  9       4  5  6       1  2  3
```

When I log arrtY in the console I only see 1.

Comment: The output I see is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: arr1 is not defined`  Can you provide a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Remove first two `return`s.

Comment: @Igor Thanks sir. However the resulting array is 12 entries long and not the entries are not in the expected order. I think I could fix this but any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution

```
const transY =(arr)=> {
    const arrtY = []; 
    function rowpush(i) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            arrtY.push(arr[3*i+j]);
        }
    }
    rowpush(2);
    rowpush(0);
    rowpush(1);
    return arrtY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```js
function transform(arr) {
  var res = [];
  for(var i = 6; res.length < 9; i = (i + 1) % 9)
    res.push(arr[i]);
  return res;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
arr = transform(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
arr = transform(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```